# A property of $F_\sigma$ sets.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am self studying topology from C. Wayne patty and I am unable to think how to proceed with this question whose image is added. ( Exercise 1.5 question 13(c) ) .

[image]

It seems that some construction has to be done in terms of sets but I am unable to construct those sets.

My attempt-> I tried by thinking that $F_\sigma$ is an countable union of closed sets but there is no surety that they are contained in one another and not even need to intersect. So, I am unable to think foreword on how to construct such a set.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have edited it. Kindly have a look.

Comment: How about b)? Do you know how to take the complement of a union of sets?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have problem only in ( C) part and I have mentioned it in question!!

Comment: If $A$ is the union of closed sets  $D_1,D_2,..$ then it is also the union of $D_1, D_1 \cup D_2, D_1 \cup D_2\cup D_3,...$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is an $F_\sigma$, so $A= \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} F_n$ for a sequence $(F_n)$ of closed sets of $X$.

Now, finite unions of closed sets are closed, so $C_n = \bigcup_{i \le n} F_i$ is closed for each $n$.

- $C_{m} \subseteq C_{m+1}$ for all $m$ is clear, because we take a union of one more set.
- $\bigcup_n C_n = \bigcup_n F_n$ because $F_n \subseteq C_n$ for all $n$ and if $x$ is in some $C_n$ it must be in some $F_i$ as well.

So the $C_n$ are as required.

Answer (score 0):

Begin with the countable collection of closed sets which 'make' $\cal A$ an $F_\sigma$ (by union). Now use de Morgan's Laws and the fact that the complement of a closed set is open.

Comment: He's asking about (c), not (b).

Comment: Yes, I realized that later. Oops.